# AngularJS: Two Parallel Views, One URL

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, deep-linking

I'm building a dashboard/control panel app that is basically made up of two tabs (bootstrap) at the root level, called "dispatch" and "admin". Each tab has a good bit of its own multi-tiered navigation and functionality, and they don't need to directly interact with each other. The problem I'm running into is how to deep-link to sub-views within one of the tabs without losing the "state" of the inactive tab. To clarify, I can achieve this just fine if I don't worry about updating the URL, but when I try to add deep-linking, that's when I get stuck.

An example of the desired behavior:

1. When you click on the "Admin" tab, the route becomes `"/admin"`
2. Click on a sub-nav item, route becomes `"/admin/foo"`
3. Select 3rd-tier sub-level item, route becomes `"admin/foo/thing1"`
4. Click on the "dispatch" tab, route becomes `"/dispatch"`
5. Click back on the "admin" tab, route goes back to `"admin/foo/thing1"`

So basically, if you're at the `"admin/foo/thing1"` route in the middle of filling out a text field, then switch to another tab, then switch back, the text field should still be there just as you left it.

Like I said, the problem isn't switching from tab to tab, since by default the tabs just show and hide things on the page without reloading any views dynamically. I just don't know how to deep-link to a given tab's "bookmarked" position when you switch to it. The way I keep thinking of it is that clicking on a tab should only update the first segment of the URL(`/admin` or `/dispatch`), and then some sort of $watch function would update the remaining segments based on the last "location" within that tab. Would something like that work?

Also, I'm using ui-router to handle all my routing and states, so I have to factor that into how I'm going to handle the desired behavior.

Help?

Comment: Could you post some of your code? A working jsFiddle or something would be best.

Comment: Sure thing. Here's a Plunker I put together that mimics what I'm trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pv0tOn?p=preview

Comment: (accidentally submitted that last one too soon...)

It shows the current path based on the link you click inside the Admin panel, but what I want it to look like is to have the first segment switch between "Admin" and "Dispatch", and when you switch back to "Admin", have the URL update to whatever the path was before you switched to "Dispatch".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked on both those topics (deep state reactivation and parallel states) and integration into ui-router.  Grab my github fork of ui-router and build using grunt. Then, mark your two tab states as `parallel: true` and `deepStateRedirect: true`.

Git repo:  https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router

Example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YhQyPV?p=preview

Discussion: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/894

Comment: Holy crap... this is literally exactly what I'm trying to do! Thank you so much, I cannot believe how perfect this is. Major props to you, good sir.

Comment: This is a feature that is actively being discussed for addition into mainline ui-router.  Add to the discussion at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/894 if you have any thoughts or ideas for improvement.

Comment: Nice work chris. Can't believe your not getting more up votes.

Comment: UPDATE: IT WORKS. OMG IT WORKS. I OWE YOU SO MANY BEERS.

Comment: QUESTION: If my `/admin` and `/dispatch` tabs are parallel, and I navigate to `/admin/settings/config`, where 'settings' and 'config' are actually state params that dynamically load a view and a controller, I noticed that when switching to Dispatch and back to Admin, the state params don't persist (as in, the route simply goes back to `/admin` instead of `admin/settings/config`). Is there something I need to do to make that work?

Comment: @mklickman I have tested with state params, but not with a dynamically loaded view and controller.  In my plunkr, the first and third tabs have state params.  It sounds like you may not be using the deepStateRedirect config option.  However, if you are indeed using deepStateRedirect, I'm interested in fixing bugs in my ui-router fork so if you can send me a plunkr test case, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: @ChrisT so I've got parallel views working ok, but for some reason I can't get my model data to persist across view changes, like in your example plunker (the input fields). Would you be able to look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you can get it into a plunkr, I'll take a look

Comment: UPDATE: My git repo is no longer current!  The parallel states code has been released as a UI-Router addon called [UI-Router Extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky) Sticky States

Answer (score 0):

I would just save the current state in a variable, then either dynamically change the link of the tab to whatever the last subview was.

For example, if the user is on `/admin/billing`, the Admin tab would link to `admin/billing`. When they leave that tab, the `/admin` tab remains the same. If you are using ui-router, you can do this with `ui-sref`s. You could also just manually check the variable when the state changes, and route the user there from the controller.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see where you're going. The problem with actually following a link, like if clicking the tab actually followed a ui-sref route, is that it would reload the view, causing whatever was happening in the tab initially to get reloaded (like if you were filling out a text box in admin, then switched to dispatch, that contents would be reset when switching back to admin). I don't need to actually trigger a view change, I just need to show the appropriate tab and update the url *without* updating a view.

Comment: Try using multiple views? Create two named views for each tab? Maybe just save any input fields as a tempState variable with help from the onExit callback? I think that what you are trying to do isn't actually routing so much as it is just trying to show the state in the url and save progress (both are byproducts of keeping track of state).

Comment: That's a good point, because yeah, it's less about actually following routes, and more about keeping track of two parallel states, where only the details of the current state are visible. I guess the big thing I don't know how to do is update the URL when simply changing tab visibility, as opposed to truly following a link.